# What's wrong with my code in JS?

Tags: javascript, variables

I just started learning Javascript and I don't know what's wrong with code... I am trying to print the values of my variables.

```
var name='John';
var age='25';

console.log(name + age);
console.log(age + age);

var job, isMarried;

console.log(job);

job = 'teacher';
isMarried = false;

console.log(name + ' ' + age ' ' + job ' ' + isMarried ' ');
```

I am getting the following error:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"
```

I see this means missing syntax but being new I am not sure what I forgot?

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong? Give a [mcve].

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to JS, it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" and I have no idea what is that...

Comment: What should `job ' '` do?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a few + symbols

```js
var name='John';
var age='25';

console.log(name + age);
console.log(age + age);

var job, isMarried;

console.log(job);

job = 'teacher';
isMarried = false;

console.log(name + ' ' + age + ' ' + job + ' ' + isMarried + ' ');
```

Comment: Best of luck in your coding journey @Zach ! Remeber to always include what your problem is, what you have tried, and what you expect to happen. If this helps, please mark as answer. Cheers.